# How to update python functions in airflow without the need to restart airflow webserver

Tags: python, airflow

I'm learning to use airflow to schedule some python ETL processes. Each time I update my python code I have to restart the webserver and also rename the DAG before code changes are picked up by airflow. Is there anyway around this, especially so I dont have to be renaming my DAG each time I make changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the webserver the changes may not be apparent but you can click the refresh button next to the DAG that you modify and it will reload the DAG manually.

The scheduler will always use the latest code without need for a reboot.

See here: https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html

Answer (score -1):

This has been an issue with the current version. What I usually do is to duplicate the DAG and change its name so it reflects in the web server. As soon as I finish developing I keep the last renamed and delete the old ones.

Answer (score -4):

This URL: 
http://airflowhost:8080/admin/airflow/refresh_all

refreshes all the dags

Comment: Consider providing a **screenshot** / `doc` **link**; the given URL won't open

Comment: link goes to 404

Comment: The link that @user7126545 provided is a POST request. I cannot find it in the documentation but the Airflow source contains a mention of it: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/728518224b9c6469c74b66d9d2b47b13de00fc8c/airflow/www/views.py#L2148